# Using actions class to scroll to bottom of page, clicking on any other element opening unwanted right-click context menu

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Actions to scroll to the bottom of the page:

```
public void scrollToBottomPage(){
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
}
```

but in next step, I have to click on the back button(available in my web application).

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.terraVM-ActionToolbar-button--back")).click();
```

Selenium webdriver is opening unwanted right-click context menu and my script is getting failed.

Using chrome browser with latest selenium webdriver jar and chrome browser jar.

Working on mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

I was not releasing CONTROL button in next:

```
public void scrollToBottomPage(){
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).release().perform();
```

}

Silly mistake.. :P